# Python Panda Issues with Converting Large JSON file to Unique Values

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am very new to Panda, so forgive me if I am just not understanding something. I have a 'large' JSON file of around 72 MB, and I am looking to pull the following information out of it. The Agent_UUID, The CVE and the Name of the CVE in question for that asset.

So, lets say the the Agent_UUID was John Smith.

I would like for every CVE and the Name that is attached to John Smith.

Below is an example of a single JSON inside of that JSON file

```
[
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "John Smith",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "redacted",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "0redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cve": [
                "Bad Exploit 1"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "Credacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "redacted",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "NONE",
        "state": "open"
    }
],
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "John Smith",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "redacted",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "0redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cve": [
                "Bad Exploit 1"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "Credacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "redacted",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "NONE",
        "state": "open"
    }
]
]
```

The Next JSON in the file will look exactly like above, but it might say for the CVE and Name Bad Exploit 2.

I would like for the output to say something along the lines of

John Smith- Bad Exploit 1 Badexploit 2 and so on.

The Code I am using to make this work is the following

```
j=open('assets.json',)
data=json.load(j)
results= pd.json_normalize(
    data, "agent_uuid", ["cve","name"])
print(results)
```

When I attempted this, I got the following output error code.

```
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\Desktop\Python Projects\Exports.Vulns\Exports.Vulns\Exports.Vulns.py", line 45, in <module>
    results= pd.json_normalize(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 519, in json_normalize
    _recursive_extract(data, record_path, {}, level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 501, in _recursive_extract
    recs = _pull_records(obj, path[0])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 423, in _pull_records
    result = _pull_field(js, spec, extract_record=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 400, in _pull_field
    result = result[spec]
             ~~~~~~^^^^^^
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This is what happens when I attempt Builditluc's recommendation

```
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1, step=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\Desktop\Python Projects\Exports.Vulns\Exports.Vulns\Exports.Vulns.py", line 50, in <module>
    agent_uuid = data["asset.agent_uuid"] # note the "asset."
                 ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3761, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 349, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'asset.agent_uuid'
```

Here is the rest of my code as well, just in case this is doing something to mess up this file. I did this in order to allow it to read as a JSON for validation.

```
#Iterating through the JSON Output and dumping into Assets.json 
print("starting Json Output")
with open("assets.json", 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    outfile.write("[")
    for vuln in redacted():
        outfile.write("[")
        outfile.write("\n")
        json.dump(vuln, outfile, 
                        indent=4)
        outfile.write("],")
        outfile.write("\n")
        print("Working")

#Removes the final , at the end of the file
with open('assets.json', 'rb+') as cleanup:
    cleanup.seek(-3, 2)
    cleanup.truncate()

#Appends the final ] to the end of the file
with open("assets.json", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as finalbracket:
    finalbracket.write("]")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\Desktop\Python Projects\Exports.Vulns\Exports.Vulns\Exports.Vulns.py", line 59, in <module>
    agent_uuid = data["asset.agent_uuid"] # note the "asset."
                 ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3761, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 349, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'asset.agent_uuid'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

When I modified the code to see what output I get, which is just removing the Agent and the CVE part of it.

```
file = open("assets.json",)
file_json = json.load(file)

for file in file_json: # "assets.json" contains an array of data
    data = pd.json_normalize(file_json) # here we load the json data into a DataFrame
    print(data)
```

I got the following output

```
                                                   0
0  {'first_found': 'redacted', 'indexed': 'redact...
1  {'first_found': 'redacted', 'indexed': 'redact...
                                                   0
0  {'first_found': 'redacted', 'indexed': 'redact...
1  {'first_found': 'redacted', 'indexed': 'redact...
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am not sure why, but shouldn't Assets be the first thing in this output?

Comment: The json snippet you provided is not valid json. Could you please provide us with a valid json snippet so we can look into possible solutions? EDIT: The snippet doesn't have to include all of your data fields (for example the `redacted` fields, if the error occurs without them), just the ones needed for the error to occur

Comment: The `KeyError` occurs when the column specified doesn't exist which is weird because it works with your provided sample. Could you add the available column names to your question?

Comment: Your included code definitely does something with the file, does its output match your provided code sample?

Comment: Yes it does. I added another example of how it is formatted inside the Json but just copy and pasted it. Basically at the beginning of every output from this API it doesn't have any brackets or anything separating one JSON from another. So I added one at the beginning and at the end with a comma at the end to allow the JSON file to still remain a JSON file when it needs to be used later.

Comment: I've updated my answer and tried explaining how the file is structured so you know why the code had to be modified this way. The provided code sample works with the json file you've given in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `pandas.json_normalize` loads json data, normalizes it and returns it in a `DataFrame` (for examples, see the pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html?highlight=json_normalize)).

You can now use the returned DataFrame to get the values of specific columns using `frame[column_name]` (the columns are derived from your json file

What you now have to pay attention to is that you merge the output from your `reacted()` function into a single json file.

If you now want to extract the data, you have to iterate over the content of the json file. This is because your json file contains an array of tables, each item being one data entry.

With the following code, we can extract the `agend_uuid` and `cve` values for every data entry in the file

```
import json
import pandas as pd

file = open("assets.json",)
file_json = json.load(file)

for file in file_json: # "assets.json" contains an array of data
    data = pd.json_normalize(file) # here we load the json data into a DataFrame

    agent_uuid = data["asset.agent_uuid"] # note the "asset."
    cve = data["plugin.cve"] 

    print(agent_uuid)
```

With your provided json sample, the output is the following

```
0    John Smith
Name: asset.agent_uuid, dtype: object
0    John Smith
Name: asset.agent_uuid, dtype: object
```

I hope I could help you!

Comment: I have added more information to the post, and showed your error code. Hopefully this will be helpful

Comment: I posted above the error I got doing this, and this is with the data I have given you so I am really sure why this doesn't work as it should.

Comment: Oh yes I see. My mistake, the first line in the for loop... we should be using file and not file_json.

Comment: I should have saw that as well, sorry about that. I will let you know how it goes from there.

Comment: Everything appears to be working properly. I just have to sanitize some data on my end, but thank you very much for your assistance on this!